# Error in creating a database security store for every domain (Weblogic)

Tags: weblogic

Welcome

I have two domain in the same machine and i want to create database security store for every one but when run the following script for second domain the notification error message is displayed
"Security store already created ".

`./wlst.sh   &lt;IAM_HOME&gt;/common/tools/configureSecurityStore.py -d &lt;domaindir&gt; -c IAM -p "Welcome1" -m create`

So
can I create a  database security store for every domain in the same machine ?  and how ?

Answer (score 0):

> In a multiple-domain scenario, the command to **create the Database
>   Security Store is executed once** after the first domain is created
>   but before the domain is started for the first time.

[Configuring Database Security Store for an OIAM Domain](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/core/INOAM/db_securitystore.htm#INOAM98436)